# Production server AJAX calls very slow compared to the same calls on local server

Tags: ajax, performance, firebug, yslow

I've come across this problem recently after changing production servers.

My application is very slow on the production server compared to the same application on a local server. Pending some investigation, it's the AJAX calls (made to an API located on another, external server). Whilst on my local server an AJAX call returns in a matter of miliseconds, on the production server the call is marked as PENDING in firebug and returns with a latency of up to 5-6 seconds.

Everything else seems fine, the page gets a 70/100 speed score, and in production (ONLY!) the high priority page speed suggestion is: Reduce your response times to make your page load faster.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: check the performance of the production server... check where the time is spent... is it on network transfer or server processing

Comment: if the database on your local test server is way smaller than the database on your production server, and the db is poorly designed (no indexes) the queries may need a lot of time to execute, hence the delay.